# Big O time complexity for itertools combinations

Tags: python

I created a code using itertools combination. The code snippet is below. What is the Big O complexity? Is it O(n!)?

```
a_list =[ 'A', 'B','C' ]
all_combinations = []
for r in range(len(a_list) + 1):
    combinations_object = itertools.combinations(a_list, r)
    combinations_list = list(combinations_object)
    all_combinations += combinations_list

print(all_combinations)
[(), (A,), (B,), (C,), (A, B), (A, C), (B, C), (A, B, B)]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated, but the last one is `A, B, C`, right?

Comment: yes. it is a typo

Answer (score 0):

Getting all combinations of a list is `O(n!)`. Since you're doing that `n` times to get combinations with different values of `r`, the whole algorithm is `O(n*n!)`.