# Isn't the time complexity for combinations in Python O(n)?

Tags: python, time-complexity, combinations

I was curious about the time complexity of Python's `itertools.combinations` function. I did some searching and it seems that many resources claim the time complexity is [O(n!)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66862413/) or [O(nCr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419536/what-is-the-computational-complexity-of-itertools-combinations-in-python).

However, for the two extremes of when `r = 1` and `r = n`, the formula `nCr` reduces to `n` and `1`, respectively. Does this mean we can conclude that the time complexity of `itertools.combinations` is O(n)?

Comment: Surely you can't be serious...

Comment: @KellyBundy Unfortunately my seriousness is real. Why wouldn't this logic hold?

Comment: Bah, your first sentence is close, [second isn't](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_XuPXGMpLA).

Comment: It has to be at least O(1) for every output produced.  How many outputs will there be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

r=1 and r=n rather are (almost) *best* cases (actually r=0 is the lower extreme), not *worst* cases. Worst case, at least for number of combinations, is r=n/2. So if you do want to express the complexity in terms of just n, it's O(nC(n/2)) or O(n × nC(n/2)), depending on what you do with the tuples.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean we can conclude that the time complexity of `itertools.combinations` is `O(n)`?

No you / we can't do that.

Consider this statement:

> Algorithm X to compute the combinations of r values from a set of n  is `O(nCr)`.

It is in fact trivial to prove<sup>1</sup> that *any* algorithm to do the above **must** be *at least* `O(nCr)`.  But we would need to examine the actual code to determine that a *given* algorithm is *exactly* `O(nCr)`

What you are doing is setting one or both of the variables to fixed values. This is effectively *changing the problem*.

To illustrate this, we can just substitute the fixed values into the above statement; e.g.

> Algorithm X to compute the combinations of 1 value from a set of n  is `O(nC1)`.

Since `nC1` is `n`, we can rewrite this as:

> Algorithm X to compute the combinations of 1 value from a set of n  is `O(n)`.

But notice that *this problem is different* to the original one.

In short ... this is NOT invalidating the original statement.

---

Note that the (alleged) claim that `itertools.combinations` is `O(n!)` is (I think) a misreading on your part.  What that "source" actually says is:

> *"Getting all combinations of a list is O(n!). Since you're doing that n times to get combinations with different values of r, the whole algorithm is O(n * n!)."*

My reading is that it is talking about `Pn` not `nCr`.  But either way, it is too vague to be considered a credible source.

---

<sup>1 - Informal proof.  The set of combinations of r from a set of n has `nCr` elements.  Constructing this set will entail adding `nCr` elements to a data structure.  That involves (at least) `nCr` memory writes.  It will take (at least) `O(nCr)` time to do this ... assuming a (real world) computer with an upper limit on memory bandwidth.</sup>